# Branch locus equal up to an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be projective varieties and $f_1:X  \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ and $f_2:Y  \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ morphisms. If $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, how can I justify that branch locus of $f_1$ is equal (or isomorphic) to the branch locus of $f_2$?

Comment: Just like your [last question on this subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745376/branch-locus-of-birational-map), something's up here - there's no reason for this to be true. I suspect you're encountering an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and if that's correct it would be better for everyone involved if you followed the advice on that webpage in regards to posting your underlying question. Even if that's not the case, your question is missing a good amount of context - where did you meet this problem, why do you care, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is false; for example, you could take $n = 1$ and $X = Y = \mathbb{P}^1$ and take $z \mapsto z^5$ and the identity map for $f_1$ and $f_2$.